# PHP. "?>" on top of page

Tags: php

I am creating site with php.
On localhost all works well.
On my hosting all looks good too, but on top of page i see "?>". In my code these symbols are absent.

What is this?

Comment: your information is pretty vague

Comment: could you place here a code snippet of the returned HTML ?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific: How does your script look like? When and where do you see the `?>`?

Comment: Do you have a php script inside your php file? Like: <?php // code ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that your code uses short open tags (`<?` instead of `<?php`) and your hosting provider has short open tags turned off. That would mean, however, that your PHP code is not interpreted at all. It could also mean that your hosting provider doesn't support PHP at all, or only for certain file types.

Take a look into the page's source code to check whether that is the case.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you see that on top of the page could mean one or more things.

1. It seems you have typed in `?>`
   outside of a php block
2. You may be using short tags `<?`
   instead of long `<?php` and the host
   has short tags turned off

Out of these its most likely you have a closing `?>` in your code without a corresponding open `<?php` tag

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure yu're seeing `?>` and not something like `>>?` ?

Otherwise, this smells like a PHP-EndTag which was never opened...check your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a empty lines in your sourcefile before the opening `<?php`-tag, then those empty lines could get outputted unintenionally. If your script should start with `<?php` on top, remove all the empty lines above it.